# Каким образом можно вывести компьютер из спящего режима программно?

Tags: bios

Или это нереально? Не совсем знаком с этой частью работы компьютера.

Comment: То что я знаю: можно через устройство выводить из спящего режима (есть галка в настройках питания вроде или драйвера).
Не представляю как можно программно с того же компьютера можно его разбудить. Можно разбудить и включить выключенный, при включенной поддержке WOL (Wake On Lan) с другого компьютера по сети.

Comment: У многих компьютеров в биосе есть возможность выставить время включения компьютера. В теории, можно и программно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В Windows для это существуют [System Wake-up Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa373235(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Приложение может пробудить компьютер из спящего режима в рабочее состояние с помощью таймера или события устройства. Что называется пробуждением по событию. Используйте [Waitable Timer Objects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687012(v=vs.85).aspx), чтобы указать время, в которое система должна быть разбужена. Для создания объекта используйте функцию [CreateWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682492(v=vs.85).aspx). Для установки таймера используйте функцию [SetWaitableTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686289(v=vs.85).aspx). Параметр PDueTime определяет, когда таймер подаст сигнал. Чтобы указать, что система должна быть разбужена, когда сработает таймер, параметр fResume должен быть TRUE.

Comment: Спасибо, буду читать.

А с выключенным что делать? Реально ли?

Comment: С выключенным не реально, он же не в состоянии выполнять любые команды.

Comment: Нет, ну так:
1. Программа устанавливает что-то в биосе(как Wake Alarm), и выключает комп.
2. В нужное время комп включается.

Не сам по себе.

Comment: Отмечу, что для того, чтобы это работало, необходимо, чтобы компьютер был в дежурном режиме. Т.е. выключен, но под напряжением. Это справедливо для современных системных блоков АТХ.

Для старых ПК с блоками питания AT ф-ция Wake Alarm недоступна, т.к. ПК отключается тумблером, т.е. полностью обесточивается.

Answer (score 2):

Из спящего... По-моему, можно сигналом на сетевую карту WakeOnLan (подключается специальный кабель). А еще, мне кажется, можно заранее программно задать время включения (написать программу), но, напоминаю, заранее должно быть задано время включения. А просто вывести из спящего режима без заранее установленой програмы, я считаю, невозможно. Разве что подключить внешний модуль, который сможет это сделать.

Comment: Мне и нужно заранее. В биосе же есть WakeOn Alarm. Как бы воспользоваться этим программно? Ну установить его не через биос, а из ОС поставить время и вперед.
Где бы почитать на эту тему что-то?

Comment: Знаю что такое есть, но как это написать не знаю(

Comment: Жаль. Спасибо.